# how to move up the text in CSS footer?

Tags: css

I have a small text in the footer. The text is aligned to right but i want the text to move up slightly? how can I do that? my code

```
#foot tag {
    width:1000px;
    height:30px;
    padding:10px;
    border:5px solid white;
    margin:0px; 
    text-align:right; 
    padding-top: 10px;    
}
```

Comment: Add padding-botton:20px

Comment: Unless there is more to the question, it seems like this could have been resolved by doing a simple search for the answer.

Comment: @Christopher I have searched enough and been trying to solve this since half an hour. still its not perfectly getting right. but thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
#foot tag {
    width:1000px;
    height:30px;
    padding:10px 10px 20px 10px; 
    /* You can adjust the above 4 values to add padding to top, right, bottom and left */
    border:5px solid white;
    margin:0px; 
    text-align:right; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple things, it's tough to say without seeing the live site.

1) decrease the top padding by changing:

```
padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
```

2) use a negative top margin:

```
margin: -5px 0 0 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Top and left css property will move you p in parent div

```
<div style="position: relative"><p style="position: absolute; top: 1px"></p></div>
```